# WSO2 EI : text xmlns is getting added after transforming message by xslt mediator

Tags: xslt, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am transforming xml message into csv using xslt mediator. Transforming is happening fine but in the output message 
 is getting added on its own. Output message shown below

```
<text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">E5cjHWs_9N5ZiSWuvMHg_7Bhlxka|admin@xyz.super|admin|Test_API/|3.0|time|time|time|time|time|time|time|time|2018-09-25 11:51|time|time|time
</text>
```

Can some one please let me know how to remove them from the output file. Though in the log file the message looks good but actual message do have this added.

Any help pls...

Comment: Difficult to say without more details. Have you set the content-type? E.g. <property name="Content-Type" value="text/plain" scope="transport" type="STRING"></property>

Comment: Thanks for response.
Yes i have set up below properties

<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/plain"/>
            <property name="MessageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/plain"/>

Comment: Please let me know if you want to see the proxy configuration as well...

Comment: Try to set the scope="axis2" to scope="transport"

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same right now. Will post comment in few seconds..

Comment: its still there ... This is the output I am getting
<text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"> field1|field2|field3... </text>
Although namespace is not there in the log file

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked.
I had to put payloadFactory after xslt mapping to remove the xmlns
Below code I added

```
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" 
value="text/plain"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="text">
            <format>$1</format>
            <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body//*" 
    xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
```